# Test Notification bar icons using uiautomator

Tags: android, notifications

I am new to UI Automator.I have an application running as a service. It shows an icon on the notification bar

Is there any way to test this newly added icon on the top Notification bar ? I see no contol with uiautomatorviewer

or If there is any way to get icon information from NotificationMgr API please let me know it would be helpful

Comment: I haven't got any solution yet. plz let me know the possible ways to get the icon information from status/notification bar

Answer (score 3):

For notifications:

```
    private UiObject getNotificationStackScroller()
{
    /*
     * access Notification Center through resource id, package name, class name.
     * if you want to check resource id, package name or class name of the specific view in the screen,
     * run 'uiautomatorviewer' from command.
     */
    UiSelector notificationStackScroller = new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.systemui")
            .className("android.view.ViewGroup")
            .resourceId(
                    "com.android.systemui:id/notification_stack_scroller");
    UiObject notificationStackScrollerUiObject = mDevice.findObject(notificationStackScroller);
    assertTrue(notificationStackScrollerUiObject.exists());

    return notificationStackScrollerUiObject;
}
```

and the access any "i-th" item through:

```
UiObject notificationUiObject = getNotificationStackScroller().getChild(new UiSelector().index(i));
        assertTrue(notificationUiObject.exists());
```

and for example check if number of notifications is "3" exits:

```
            UiObject numberOfNotifications = notificationUiObject.getChild(new UiSelector().text("3"));
        assertTrue(numberOfNotifications.exists());
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in my case (MI 5s), assert for exists() fails randomly. Must be related to timing issues, but couldn't find the cause.

Answer (score 3):

The [UiDevice.openNotification method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#openNotification()), added in API level 18, will programmatically open the notification drawer.

**Usage Example**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) 
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {

        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        assertEquals("com.mydomain.myuiautomatortests", appContext.getPackageName());

        appContext.startActivity(new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class));

        UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mDevice.openNotification();
    }
}
```

**Gradle Dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'  // or higher
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring down the notification tray and then check for items in the Status bar. They will be then populated in uiautomatorviewer.

Comment: This implies manual interaction with the StatusBar.  Kinda defeats the purpose of automated testing...